# Send custom intent from desktop application to android phone

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, desktop-application

I am developing an android application which logs data on the phone onto a SQLite database. 
When the phone is connected to the computer via USB I need my desktop application to send a signal to my phone that it should lock all the tables and start copying the database (to the SD card and then to the desktop).

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using ADB? Run a script that copies the database tables off the phone?

Answer (score 1):

You should use network communication, by sending a tcp or an udp package to the android phone, from your application.

Something like [that](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example) or [that](http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/).

You will find an explanation on Java language [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html).

Comment: Cén't vote up yet.. Thanks for your response ! it helps me get on the right track !